# Minimize absolute difference between shortest paths

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I am trying to solve the following shortest path problem:

> There are 2 friends travelling to a city C from cities A and B (one starts at A, the other at B). Find
>   the shortest paths that these 2 friends could take from A to C and B to
>   C that minimizes the absolute difference between the distance of the 2
>   shortest paths.

I am thinking that using computing shortest paths from A to C and B to C and taking their difference might just work. I do not know whether my solution is correct or how to prove it. Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Counterexample: mindist(A,C) = 10, mindist(B, C) = 1, otherdist(B, C) = 10.

Comment: If the paths must be simple (i.e., no vertex can be visited twice), then this is NP-hard by reduction from Hamiltonian Cycle: Given an n-vertex graph G = (V, E) for which you want to find a HC, turn it into an instance of your problem in by letting (A, C) be any edge in G, and adding a vertex B and edge (B, C) with length n-1.  This forces a length-(n-1) simple path from A to C to be found, if such exists -- which, together with (A, C), is a HC.

Comment: @j_random_hacker very elegant reduction proof.

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekBansal :)